# starting a activity in android opens multiple instance of new activity Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a file CartActivity.kt from which I make an external API call. If the API call is successful it launches an activity called CurrentOrders.

```
val currentOrdersIntent = Intent(this@CartActivity, CurrentOrdersActivity::class.java)
currentOrdersIntent.putExtra("orderListObj",orderListObj)
currentOrdersIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION                                    
Toast.makeText(this@CartActivity,"${response.body()?.message}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
startActivity(currentOrdersIntent)
finish()
```

My CurrentActivity code contains a recyclerview and a button that makes a call to external API.

My problem is that once I reach currentOrders from cartactivity I have to press back button 4-5 times before it reaches the activity that started the cartactivity.

Ideally what I want
if Activity A starts cartactivity which in turn starts currentactivity, so after I press back from current activity it should route me to activity A.

Here is the link to [CartActivity](https://github.com/aniketbote/food-grain-app/blob/master/FF/app/src/main/java/com/example/farmfresh/Activities/CartActivity.kt). Link to [CurrentActivity](https://github.com/aniketbote/food-grain-app/blob/master/FF/app/src/main/java/com/example/farmfresh/Activities/CurrentOrdersActivity.kt).
This is the link for [Complete-project](https://github.com/aniketbote/food-grain-app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am getting is your CurrentOrders is getting started multiple times. you can do something like this to make it a single instance. but you need to check why it's getting started multiple times. mean while you can

just try to add this to your affected activity which one is getting duplicated in manifest.

```
<activity ..
  android:launchMode= "singleInstance" />
```

Comment: How should I check if it is starting multiple times? The above code is what I use to start the activity.

Comment: Although it did solve the problem but I have no idea what made it start multiple instances. Also there is a slight animation change. Is there any way to make use of default animation?